# How to get author info of comments of page posts?

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I already know how to do it by using the explorer api, but I'm not having success doing this.

```
 FB.api(
        page-id?fields=access_token&access_token=[USER-ACCESS-TOKEN],
        'GET',
        function (response) {                       
                 console.log("Token = " + response.access_token); //I'm using this guy here, but it still doesn't work                                               
                    }
                );
```

With this access_token returned, I still can't get the author's info when they comment on a post on my page.

Comment: the title was misleading, you ARE getting a page token already, so i fixed it. about the author info: did you check out the changelog? maybe it is just not possible to get author info for data privacy reasons.

Comment: I checked it, it's still possible and I can, but first I have to go to explorer graph api then I select the page and get my access_token.
The problem is I want to do this process programmatically

Comment: ok, that is not possible. you can only get user tokens on user interaction. would make the whole point of expiring tokens pointless if that would be possible.

Comment: You know, through an app we can get user's access token, when they log in, a window is open, showing them the permissions that they'd allow the app to use. In the same way, I'd like to do it, similarly to get the Fan Page's Acess Token.
As I said, I can get this Fan page access token on the explorer graph api there, but I can't send all my users to this site, I'd like to put a button on my web site so that they'd allow their fan pages's permissions on my website.

Comment: why would you send users to the api explorer? of course you would have to create a login page. you are using the js sdk already anyway, just present a button and call FB.login with the correct scope. now i really don´t know what your question is, to be honest...

Comment: I wanna be able to get a fan page's access token on my website.
my scope are email,public_profile,manage_pages

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182611/discussion-between-joab-and-luschn).

Comment: that is what your code is for, you got it right there in your question. you do know that you will have to go through a review process before those permissions work for everyone, right?

Comment: Yes I do. Now It's on development